# unicode-math with XeLaTeX \left( and \right) not rendered correctly

Tags: xetex, unicode-math, rendering, stix, parentheses

I'm using XeLaTeX (XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015)) on OS X Sierra, compiling to a PDF through `rubber`

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% rubber: set program xelatex
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}

\begin{document}
This is the problem $\frac{\left(asdf\right)}{\left(ghjk\right)}$
\[ \frac{\frac{\left(asdf\right)}{\left(ghjk\right)}}{\frac{\left(asdf\right)}{\left(ghjk\right)}} \]
\[ \frac{\left(asdf\right)}{\left(ghjk\right)} \]
\begin{align*}
    \frac{\frac{\left(asdf\right)}{\left(ghjk\right)}}{\frac{\left(asdf\right)}{\left(ghjk\right)}} \\
    \frac{\left(asdf\right)}{\left(ghjk\right)} 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Using the STIX 2.0.0 fonts with unicode-math and XeLaTeX causes the parentheses with `\left(` and `\right)` to render incorrectly (as a boxed question mark), while the regular `(` and `)` characters render correctly. I don't get the same problem with `\left[` and `\right]`.

The only difference in the log output is a bunch of the following lines:
`Missing character: There is no Ⴞ in font STIX Two Math/OT:script=math;language=
DFLT;!
Missing character: There is no Ⴟ in font STIX Two Math/OT:script=math;language=
DFLT;!`

Can anyone help me come up with a fix for this?

---

Really minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\begin{document}

$\left(\right)$
$\scriptstyle\left(\right)$
$\scriptscriptstyle\left(\right)$

%\showoutput

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
Missing character: There is no Ⴞ in font STIX Two Math/OT:script=math;language=DFLT;!
Missing character: There is no Ⴟ in font STIX Two Math/OT:script=math;language=DFLT;!
Missing character: There is no ᆷ in font STIX Two Math/OT:script=math;language=DFLT;+ssty=0;!
Missing character: There is no ^^@ in font STIX Two Math/OT:script=math;language=DFLT;!
Missing character: There is no ᆸ in font STIX Two Math/OT:script=math;language=DFLT;+ssty=0;!
Missing character: There is no ^^@ in font STIX Two Math/OT:script=math;language=DFLT;!
```

Comment: Works ok for me in in texlive 2017, but not in texlive 2015 and 16 .

Comment: I can reproduce it also with TeX Live 2016, but it comes out right with TeX Live 2017/pretest.

Comment: Could be this bug: https://sourceforge.net/p/xetex/bugs/129/. Then texlive 2017 would be the way to go.

Comment: I checked the file list; they differ from 2016 and 2017 only in `tuenc.def`, but this should be of no concern. I agree with Ulrike that it could be due to the mentioned bug in XeTeX. If LuaLaTeX is feasible for you, it should work OK.